# HTTP keep connection alive without blocking on socket receive?

Tags: c, rest, http, post, https

I am using the below code to make a HTTPS `GET` request.

I'd like to keep the connection alive to make multiple requests without having to connect each time, so I set `"Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n"`. However, once I did this, the behaviour changed and the code now blocks on `BIO_read()` (equivalent to `::recv()`). Now I cannot return to process the received data.

How can I only connect once, but not block on `BIO_read()`/`::recv()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pay attention to what you read. Parse the response headers. There would be wither a "Content-Length: xxx", or "Transfer-Encoding: chunked". That woukd give you an information on where the body ends.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP/2 uses, according to the [specification](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#rfc.section.9.1), persistent connections. So it should work to replace HTTP 1.1 with HTTP/2. Note, that you then have to remove the `Connection: Keep-Alive` line, as it is prohibited in HTTP/2. It was just a hint anyway, and didn't guarantee a persistent connection (see [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive)).

*Edit:* Turns out, the [HTTP/2 support of websites](https://w3techs.com/technologies/details/ce-http2) is less than 50% now, so my answer can't be a general solution in any way. So, uhm, take it as a FYI.

Comment: I removed `"Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n"` and changed the other line to `"GET " APIKEY " HTTP/2\r\n"` but I got the response `HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported`

Comment: I suppose the server has to be configured correspondingly. Seems I somehow overestimated the server support percentage. Turns out it's less than 50% -- https://w3techs.com/technologies/details/ce-http2. So, sorry for taking your time, as this can't be a general solution per se.

Comment: No sorry needed, it only took 10 seconds. No trouble at all. Thanks for taking the time to type your answer. Will give an upvote for the effort.